# Efficiently finding an integer satisfying a certain congruence

Tags: number-theory, cryptography

I am trying to solve an exercise from a cryptography textbook and I am stuck with these specific subquestion - any kind of suggestion is welcome!

> Let $\alpha = 12$ be a generator of the group $(\mathbb{Z}_p)^{*}$ where $p = 12q+1$ is a prime and $q$ is a very large prime. Assume Alice private key is $a$.
>
> Show that it is possible to efficiently (without use of the discrete logarithm on $q$) find an integer $z$ such that $ 12^{qz} \equiv y_A^q \pmod{p}$ where $y_A = \alpha^a$

Comment: And what is $r$? It appears *ex nihilo* in the last congruence...

Comment: $r$ is actually $q$. Sorry, I made a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to find an integer $z$ such that $12^{qz} \equiv 12^{qa}$ mod $p$.  What does it take for $12^{qz}$ to be equivalent to $12^{qa}$ (mod $p$)?

Recall Euler's theorem: since $\alpha$ and $p$ are relatively prime, $\alpha^{\varphi(p)} \equiv 1$ (mod p).  But we have $\varphi(p) = p - 1 = 12q$ because $p$ is prime; thus $\alpha^{12q} \equiv 1$ (mod p).

This means that if $s$ and $t$ differ by a multiple of $12q$, then $12^s \equiv 12^t$ (mod $p$).  What does this tell you about $12^{qa}$ vs $12^{qz}$?

I can give further hints if you need them.

Comment: A triviality is to take $z = a$ but $a$ is not known as it is Alice private key. Am I missing something?

Comment: More than just "whenever $s$ and $t$ differ by a multiple of $12q$"; what you really want here is the converse: if $s$ and $t$ differ by a multiple of $12q$, *then* $12^s\equiv 12^t\pmod{p}$.

Comment: That's what I meant--I'll change the confusing wording.

Comment: Okay so qa-qz is a multiple of 12q which means a-z is a multiple of 12 which implies I only need to check 12 candidates for z?

Comment: Correct :) having only 12 cases to check is very efficient.